# gauss integral of the Phi function: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(x/2+k/x) e^{-(x-a)^2/2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, gaussian-integral

Is there an analytic solution for the following Gaussian integral?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{k}{x}) e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}}dx$$

with

- $a,k$ are both real numbers,
- $\Phi$ [CDF of the standard Gauss distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), that is, $\Phi(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt$.

I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021522/gaussian-integral-of-power-of-cdf-int-infty-infty-phixn-cdot-p/2774083#2774083), which solved the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(x) e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}}dx$.

Is it possible to extend the above solution to my case?

Comment: Yes: $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ independently of $k$

Comment: @Sal. You are right but why is it independent of $k$ ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hi Claude! I write $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}+g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is an odd function. Then because $\frac{x}{2}+\frac{k}{x}$ is also odd, the only contribution to the original integral from $\Phi$ is the constant $1/2$

Comment: @sal. This is what you could have written in the first comment (even if it is obvious). Cheers :-)

Comment: @Sal Apologize for the typo. It should be $e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}}$ with $a$ some real number. I have edited the problem. Any idea?

Comment: @MingzhouLiu in that case I doubt there is a 'nice' exact answer

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$ the problem is
$$I= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2} }
   \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{\frac{k}{x}+\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\,dx$$
that is to say
$$I=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2} }
 \,\,  \text{erf}\left(\frac{\frac{k}{x}+\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dx$$

If we expand the exponential function around $a=0$, we have
$$e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2} }=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x) \, a^n$$ which means that we face integrals
$$J_{2m+1}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^{2m+1}\,\,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2} }
 \,\,  \text{erf}\left(\frac{\frac{k}{x}+\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dx$$ since, by symmetry, $J_{2m}=0$.

Assuming $k>0$, the only one I have been able to compute is
$$J_1=2+2 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}-1\right) e^{-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}  k}$$

The coefficient of $x$ is $a\, e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}$.

*This is not much !*

Comment: Still, it is an interesting (partial) solution. I am guessing there is no closed form solution for my integral :(

Comment: @MingzhouLiu. There is no solution but the problem is interesting. Cheers :-)